# Using NDK library which is in /system/lib in Android application

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use a NDK .so library which I placed in /system/lib on my Android 4.3 Riotboard.
How to do this?
Normally the library is compiled together with the application and is on the application folder,
but I need to access the Linux file system, so this isn't enough.

How to use such a library in my app?

Comment: The documentation for `loadLibrary` says _"That file will then be searched for on the application's native library search path. This consists of the application's own native library directory **followed by the system's native library directories**."_. Or you could call `System.load` instead and specify an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the native libraries created by the Android NDK can only be used on devices running specific minimum Android platform versions
 The minimum required platform version depends on the CPU architecture of the devices you are targeting.
you can also refer this site ,so that you can get an idea about requiremnets  for using android ndk :(https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Tools)

To ensure compatibility, an application using a native library produced with the NDK must declare a  element in its manifest file, with an android:minSdkVersion attribute value of "3" or higher. For example: n application using a native library produced with the NDK must declare a  element in its manifest file, with an android:minSdkVersion attribute value of "3" or higher.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html) `/system/lib` is already in the JNI search path, so you should be able to load it via `loadLibrary` without an explicit path, however issues can appear if your `.so` file either has a version suffix (like `.so.1.2`) - Android does not support these, or if it has an external dependency that is located in a folder that is not in the search path (this can be examined by printing the dependencies of the `.so` file with `ldd`).

Comment: I already got this working, but the next step is to write and read from a file from the android file system. That's why I want to use the library in the system/lib directory. But when I try to access a file and write in it, I get the following error: fatal signal 11 (sigsegv)

Comment: You most likely will not have write access to that directory on a non rooted device, since application has the access only to the files in it's sandbox. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: My Riotboard is rooted. I need to acces files to catch interrupts from output pins. And acces the I2C bus. When just catching interrupts by polling, it works, but when I try to use the native interface with it, it doesn't work any more and I get that fatal signal 11 error.

Comment: Well if you have a rooted Android, why not make a sample console app that uses your JNI library and debug it under gdb?

Comment: @Florisvd Hello sir. Were you able to resolve this issue? Have you documented this somewhere? I am trying to do the same. Just wondering if i can do without the root access